# Bad space in quotation with csquotes and polyglossia

Tags: babel, polyglossia, csquotes, french

I use `xelatex` processing command and I want to obtain a specific result using the `\enquote` or `\textquote` commands of the `csquotes` package.

The main language of my document is french and I must obtain the result `«[space]TEXT[space]»`. When I use `polyglossia` the result is wrong ie. I obtain `«[space]TEXT»`. The final space is missing.

Since I load `babel` with `frenchb`, the result is good.

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle=true,debug=true,autopunct=true,csdisplay = true]{csquotes}

\begin{document}
  Blablab bla \enquote{aa}
\end{document}
```

**MNWE:**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{french}
\setotherlanguage{german}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\usepackage[autostyle=true,debug=true,autopunct=true,csdisplay = true]{csquotes}

\begin{document}
Blablab bla \enquote{aa}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That's a but in polyglossia, see https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/issues/145 and https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/issues/141. Your example works with `\makeatletter
\XeTeXinterchartoks 4095 \french@punctguillend = {\xpg@unskip\nobreakspace}` . I would use babel,  as it currently doesn't looks like polyglossia would address such issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bug has been resolved. With texlive 2018 and `polyglossia 2018/04/07 v1.43` the output of xelatex and polyglossia is correct again:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{french}
\setotherlanguage{german}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\usepackage[autostyle=true,debug=true,autopunct=true,csdisplay = true]{csquotes}

\begin{document}
Blablab bla \enquote{aa}
\end{document}
```

[image]