# Conflict for quotation mark spaces (csquotes, biblatex and polyglossia)

Tags: biblatex, punctuation, languages, polyglossia, csquotes

I am currently using the correction proposed on [this discussion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/395005/bad-space-in-quotation-with-csquotes-and-polyglossia) for adjusting space when french quotation marks are used.

It works fine until I used also biblatex. Biblatex does not seem to use the right quotation mark (add a space after the opening quotation mark and add one before the closing quotation mark).

Since a `csquotes` command is used the quotation marks are well positionned as expected form the other question.

In the reference (in the bibliography or when a `\cite` command is used the spaces are not well defined especially for the opening quotation mark.

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{article} 
\listfiles
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{article,
  author = {Nachname, Vorname},
  title = {Titel des Zeitschriftenartikels},
  journal = {Zeitschrift},
  year = {2006},
  volume = {6},
  pages = {19--75}
}
@BOOK{book,
  author = {Buchautor, Hans-Wilhelm},
  title = {Irgendein Buch},
  address = {Buch am Wald},
  year = {2000}
}
\end{filecontents}

\RequirePackage{polyglossia}  
\setmainlanguage{french}
\setotherlanguage{german}
\setotherlanguage{english}

\usepackage[autostyle=true,debug=true,autopunct=true,csdisplay=false]{csquotes} 
\makeatletter \XeTeXinterchartoks 4095 \french@punctguillend = {\xpg@unskip\nobreakspace}

%bibliographie
\usepackage[
bibstyle=verbose,
citestyle=verbose-ibid,
autocite=footnote, 
language=french]{biblatex}
\bibliography{\jobname}


\begin{document}

\hyphenblockquote{french}{aha ahh vazdbazofbazpofna ofna foinao}

\cite{book}
\cite{article}
\autocite{article}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

**Result:**
[image: result]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a similar settings for the begin quote sign.  But I would use babel instead of polyglossia. There it works out-of-the box and the french-module of babel is well maintained. Also the output is better: with the polyglossia work-around the spacing is too large. Or use lualatex which give better output too.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{article,
  author = {Nachname, Vorname},
  title = {Titel des Zeitschriftenartikels},
  journal = {Zeitschrift},
  year = {2006},
  volume = {6},
  pages = {19--75}
}
@BOOK{book,
  author = {Buchautor, Hans-Wilhelm},
  title = {Irgendein Buch},
  address = {Buch am Wald},
  year = {2000}
}
\end{filecontents}

\RequirePackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{french}
\setotherlanguage{german}
\setotherlanguage{english}

\usepackage[autostyle=true,debug=true,autopunct=true,csdisplay=false]{csquotes}

\makeatletter
  \XeTeXinterchartoks \french@punctguillstart 4095 = {\nobreakspace\xpg@nospace}% "«  " -> "«~"
  \XeTeXinterchartoks 4095 \french@punctguillend = {\xpg@unskip\nobreakspace}
\makeatother

%bibliographie
\usepackage[
bibstyle=verbose,
citestyle=verbose-ibid,
autocite=footnote,
language=french]{biblatex}
\bibliography{\jobname}


\begin{document}

\hyphenblockquote{french}{aha ahh vazdbazofbazpofna ofna foinao}

\cite{book}
\cite{article}
\autocite{article}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Output with babel and xelatex:

[image]

### Output with polyglossia and lualatex

[image]